# How to resolve the "No signing identity found matching 'iPhone Developer'" error when trying to run an app on a jailbroken iPhone 3GS from Eclipse?

Tags: ios, eclipse, jailbreak, robovm

I have a jailbroken iPhone 3GS, and I want to run my app, which was created using Eclipse. However, when I attempt to run the app by going to "Run As > iOS Device App," I encounter the following error: "No signing identity found matching 'iPhone Developer'."

Can someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully run my app on my jailbroken iPhone 3GS?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When RoboVM launches on a device it looks for a signing identity.

You either need to tell it to skip the signing (coz you're on a jail broken device) or specify a correct signing identity.

If you have signing identities and RoboVM isn't picking them up, make sure XCode can see them and you can see them with the 'security find-identity' command :

> $ security find-identity -v -p codesigning
>   1) ABC123 "iPhone
>    Developer: ME (ABC12345)"
>   2) DEF456 "iPhone Distribution: ME
>    (ABC34578)"

Comment: say me "0 valid identifies found" , how can i tell it to skip the signing?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.robovm.com/maven/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/iphone-sim-mojo.html. The configuration item you're after is iosSkipSigning

Comment: in eclipse project created with libGDX how to configure this 'iosSkipSigning ' ?

Comment: will be set in robovm.xml, robovm.properties o another?